# Oauth2 has problems to parse a base64 response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parsing, oauth-2.0

My API (doorkeeper) is sending a PDF in base64 to my client (Oauth2). It is unable to retrieve the base64 string.

Here is my controller action in the client (by the way the index action works fine and display data from the API without any problems) :

```
def show
    if access_token
      contrat_data=access_token.get("/api/user/contrats/#{params[:id]}").parsed
      logger.debug access_token.get("/api/user/contrats/#{params[:id]}").inspect
      @contrat=Base64.decode64 contrat_data['contrat_64']
    end
  end
```

It seems contrat_data is nil. However, the debug data is the following 
( I shortened the base64 string as it is a few ko long):

```
#<OAuth2::Response:0x249fb554 
@response=#<Faraday::Response:0x249fbb6c @on_complete_callbacks=[], 
@env=#<Faraday::Env @method=:get 
@body="{\"contrat_64   \":\"JVBERi0xLjQKMSAwIG9iago8PAovVGl0bGUgKP7/KQovQ3JlYXRvciAo/v8A\\ndwBrAGgAdABtAGwAdABvA....Aw\\nMTkKJSVFT0YK\\n\"}"

@url=#<URI::HTTP:0x24a2064c URL:http://ubuntu-syl:3000/api/user/contrats/482> 
@request=#<Faraday::RequestOptions (empty)> 
@request_headers={"User-Agent"=>"Faraday v0.9.0", "Authorization"=>"Bearer 9cd25cfbb2fc2af6f2e252826195fad3b530b388fdb9b27e55fed7a1021845db"} 
@ssl=#<Faraday::SSLOptions (empty)> 
@response_headers={"content-type"=>"text/html; charset=utf-8", "transfer-encoding"=>"chunked", "connection"=>"close", "status"=>"200 OK", "x-frame-options"=>"SAMEORIGIN", "x-xss-protection"=>"1; mode=block", "x-content-type-options"=>"nosniff", "x-ua-compatible"=>"chrome=1", "cache-control"=>"max-age=0, private, must-revalidate", "x-request-id"=>"662ddbd2-9f26-4bba-8bb7-c8e79b02e8fb", "x-runtime"=>"0.396093", "x-powered-by"=>"Phusion Passenger 4.0.53", "date"=>"Tue, 20 Jan 2015 16:29:13 GMT", "server"=>"nginx/1.6.2 + Phusion Passenger 4.0.53"} 
@status=200>>, 
@options={:parse=>nil}
>
```

The OAuth object does contain data in the body, yet the result of parsed is nil. What should be done to be able to retrieve the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in the content type. `OAuth` will try to decode the response body for you (via `parsed`) but doesn't know how to handle `text/html`, which is what you seem to be receiving. I can see two options here.

First, you can change your server's response to return a different content type. `OAuth` should be able to decode the response as JSON with `application/json` and [`a few others`](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2/blob/0ab3c213f7baa43f232eb18fa46301e1a9460f7d/lib/oauth2/response.rb#L59).

Second, you can access the raw `body` and decode it manually.

```
contrat_data_raw  = access_token.get("...")
contrat_data_json = JSON.parse(contrat_data_raw.body)
@contrat          = Base64.decode64(contrat_data_json["contrat_64"])
```

And of course you should add some error handling in case the json parsing or Base64 decoding fails.

Comment: It seems you are right, the content type returned by the API for index is application/json, i have no idea why the show action use text/html as content type.

Comment: I added `render content_type: "application/json"` to the controller action of my API and now it works. You were right.